# Add JWPlayer to setup project in VS2k10

Tags: c#, vb.net, flash, jwplayer

I need to install JWPlayer along the main program but it's not listed in the dependencies dialog. It's a Setup project type. Any ideas?

EDIT:

Website HTML code:

```
<div id="myElement">Loading the player...</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("myElement").setup({
        'fileflash': '/jwplayer/player.swf',
         'file': '/Files/123.mp4',       
        'width': 1000,
        'height': 800,
        'autostart': true
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I have not used VS2k10 before, but the player itself is just loaded in a script tag and embedded on a page using javascript.

Comment: Hmm then i guess it happens if the flash is not installed on the computer? I use WebBrowser control so most probably when flash is not installed/present the JWPlayer does not play the videos. Any ideas?

Comment: JW Player runs in HTML5 by default, Flash is a fallback. Do you have a web link for debugging?

Comment: I have no debugging link but the code is pretty simple:   
<div id="myElement">Loading the player...</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("myElement").setup({
        'fileflash': '/jwplayer/player.swf',
         'file': '/Files/123.mp4',       
        'width': 1000,
        'height': 800,
        'autostart': true
    });
</script>

Comment: That code looks fine. I need to see a link to debug properly.